# dictionary with a Type as a key typescript

Tags: angular, dictionary, typescript

I want to create a dictionary with Types as values.

f.e, in C#, i'd do: `Dictionary<Type, WhateverINeed>`, but in typescript there's really I know that can do that.

I've come across `type.d.ts` in `@angulalr/core`, but I don't know how to use it. I've seen the generic type class used the `Route` interface, where you provide the Component class for the route.

Basically, I want to create a map between a type and an `Observable` of that class

But the only dictionary key types I know can be used with Typescript's dictionary are `int` and `string`.

The usecase would be either:

```
service.method<MyClass>(...)
```

or

```
service.method(MyClass, ...)
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Are you trying to figure out the typing? You could use a generic object typing (e.g. `{ [key: string]: number }`) or a map (`Map<string, number>`).

Comment: Basically, what the first answer proposed. Gonna check his answer tomorrow. Basically, i want to save a map between a datatype and an observable of that datatype.

Comment: You said that in the question; it's not clear what it *means*. What have you tried? Where's the problem?

Comment: I didnt know what to try, this is why I approached here, after a hefty amouny of googling. I want the class to save observables mapped to types, so that one someone calls the service method with sonw type, it will either return the existing observable, or add it to the mapping. My purpose is to create a little pubsub system. Someone can subscribe, and get back an observable, and someone can publish, and behind the scene i'll call next on the wanted observable. Is that clearer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is basically type safe wrapper for `Map<,>` and it will only work with concrete classes (functions):

```
import {Type} from '@angular/core';

class Service
{
    private map = new Map<Type<any>, Observable<any>>();

    public set<T>(key:Type<T>, value:Observable<T>):void
    {
        this.map.set(key, value);
    }

    public get<T>(key:Type<T>):Observable<T>
    {
        return this.map.get(key);
    }
}

const service = new Service();


service.set(MenuModel, Observable.of(new MenuModel()));
service.set(Number, Observable.of(0));

service.get(MenuModel).subscribe(model => console.debug('menu', model.userMenu));
service.get(Number).subscribe(model => console.debug('number', model));
```

Comment: Hey man, thanks for the answer. It seems like what I need. I'll check it out after i sleep(1:15 am right now), and ill tell you if its indeed what i needed. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hey man, it helped me a lot, you're welcome to take a look at the use of it: [github commit](https://github.com/gioragutt/dp3/commit/0d0eac070fbe0437c363f7291dcc5d1fecbff4a0)